# Why isn't my Route.Ignore working on this static file in my ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Background**

I have a PDF file located (under my Project) in an Assets > Documents folder:

[image]

When my application gets deployed, it gets deployed to a particular folder on the domain. For example, http://www.domain.com/MyAppFolder. I want to be able to access this PDF file by linking to http://www.domain.com/MyAppFolder/Assets/Documents/EZTrac_UserGuide_NewSys.pdf

**Problem**

I can't seem to get the routing correct for this, as it keeps trying to route this request to a controller. Here is the modification I made to the routing:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("MyAppFolder/Assets/Documents/EZTrac_UserGuide_NewSys.pdf");
```

But this is the result that I get:

> The IControllerFactory
>   'EZTrac.DependencyResolution.ControllerFactory'
>   did not return a controller for a
>   controller named 'Assets'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the MyAppFolder from your routes.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Assets/Documents/EZTrac_UserGuide_NewSys.pdf");
```